# using excel 2007 to acess external sql database TO import>edit>export table

Tags: sql, database, excel

Is there a way or guide to connect to remote sql server were you can import>modify>export table in excel that uses the excel interface or something similar? Without having to log into the server directly. (multiple domains on one server I don't want them to access)

using the sql button in the data tab lets you import and edit the file but only lets you export to a new table(go figure)
http://i47.tinypic.com/e6qgdj.jpg

using mysql workbench is way to confusing for the user
http://i45.tinypic.com/2z4fh1f.jpg

I simply want the user to:
1. import the table into excel from external database.
2. edit database in excel.
3. export back into database overwriting old file.
http://i48.tinypic.com/2lm7zi1.jpg

The only method I can't get to work is this one. Im assuming its the one I want too.
http://i49.tinypic.com/bdjw51.jpg

Comment: MySQL Query Browser is pretty easy to use (easier than building your own data editor)